# Can SQL Transactional Replication work between SQL 2005 Standard (Publisher) and SQL 2008 R2 Web (Subscriber)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ftp, transactional-replication

I've been trying, googling and hitting my head against the wall but can't figure our what the problem is or how to solve it.

I have and SQL 2005 Standard server acting as a publisher. I need to do transactional replication to an SQL 2008 R2 Web server on another location.

I've set up the publication, and enabled FTP access to get the snapshot.

On the 2005 server when I launch replication monitor it keeps saying Uninitialized Subscription.

If I test this with a different subscriber that is running SQL 2008 Enterprise, it works fine.

Could it be because of the version? Could it be the SQL 2008 R2 Web can't work as a subscriber with SQL 2005?

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

Mixed versions are supported, but:

- Distributor version must always be equal or newer than Publisher
- Subscribers for transactional replication can be within 2 versions newer/older of Publisher
- Subscribers for merge replication must be equal or older than Publisher

You need to troubleshoot to verify initial setup. I would suggest you to setup Replication using GUI
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/ (Should be similar in SQL 2005) as well

- To do a clean installation please drop existing setup (Publisher, Subscriber, Distribution DBs)
- How to cleanup Replication Bits - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/11/17/how-to-cleanup-replication-bits.aspx

Comment: Hi Siva, I've tried cleaning the replication bits a few times now but still doesn't work. When I run it with SQL 2005 Standard as the Publisher and my local VM running 2008 R2 Enterprise it works fine. When I try to run from SQL 2005 Standard to the clients SQL 2008 R2 Web it doesn't work. If I open the replication monitor on the publisher I keep getting Uninitialized subscription.

Comment: Can you please check on - If you are using Windows authentication, please ensure that you specify it as <domain or computer name>\<user name>, and not just <user name>

Comment: I'm using SQL authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using Push or Pull subscription. The network share to copy the snapshot files. Have you provided everyone access. I would suggest to try with Windows Authentication providing UNC path full acess for the account. Without scripts if you manually set it up using SSMS, If it errors then it must be only permission issue.

Comment: I'm using Pull subscription across the Internet. The folder where the snapshot is sitting is shared to everyone, and enabled FTP access to it. If I run it from my local VM which is on a different location than the publisher, it works fine (I'm using 2008 Enterprise). When I run it from the client's VM 2008 Web it doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Are you able to connect between Distributor & Publisher & Subscriber machines, Ensure there is no Connectivity Issues, 2. Try to setup using SQL Server Mgmt Studio (GUI). If it fails for one table then it must be permission / access / network connectivity issue. Try setting up for one table

Comment: I can connect with no issue. I got the client to update to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition and it is working now. It seems to me that SQL 2008 R2 Web Edition only supports to act as a Subscriber on Push Replications. Anyways, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The comment listed below is from our SQL PFE.  I am still trying to get some documentation.

"Publisher version must be equal to or greater than the Subscriber version."